# react-joyride - How to close tutorial when clicking on the cross?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react joyride on my project. I show a simple tutorial that match this code

```
<Tutorial
        steps={[
          {
            target: `body`,
            title: `New on the website ? `,
            content: `To see how the website works, let's get started`,
            locale: {
              next: `Start`, skip: `Skip`
            },
            disableBeacon: true,
            placement: `center`
          },
          {
            target: `#search-block .wrapper-city`,
            content: `Give us information about the city`,
            placement: `top`,
            disableBeacon: true
          },
          {
            target: `#search-block .wrapper-date-range`,
            content: `Tell us the period`,
            placement: `top`
          },
          {
            target: `#search-block .wrapper-activity-type`,
            content: `Tell us the activity you would like to practice`,
            placement: `top`
          },
          {
            target: `#search-block button.btn-green`,
            content: `Finally click search `,
            placement: `top`
          }
        ]}
        joyrideProps={{ disableScrolling: true }}
        callback={(data) => {
          console.log(data);
        }}
      />
```

With this tutorial when on the first step i click on the cross to close the tutorial, it goes to the second step... but i would like to either make this cross disappear or to when we click on this cross the tutorial stops but is not ignored. Does anyone have any clue on how to avoid this behavior ?

the same behavior happens on this poc -> https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gilbarbara/react-joyride-demo

Any clue would be greatly appreciate =)

Answer (score 5):

I think you already solved the problem by yourself now. But if there is someone who might suffer the same issue, this answer could be helpful. The current behavior of react-joyride is to close the modal but kill that instance actually.

So in my case, I solved that problem by defining redux state which toggles ReactJoyride.

```
renderTutorial = () => {
    const { showTutorial } = this.props;
    return (
      <ReactJoyride
        callback={this.handleJoyrideCallback}
        continuous
        run={!!showTutorial}
        steps={scoringSteps}
        styles={{
          options: {
            zIndex: 1000,
            primaryColor: '#3698DC'
          }
        }}
      />
    )
};

handleJoyrideCallback = data => {
    if (action ===  'close') {
      this.props.endTutorial();
    }
};
```

I overrode the callback function and used it to dispatch action which changes props of showing Joyride. So that, the ReactJoyride will be invisible as we change our props as false.

FYI: **action === 'close'** will be helpful to check wether cross icon is clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem `i would like to either make this cross disappear or to when we click on this cross the tutorial stops but is not ignored` . I also had this issue and I solved it by hiding it. If someone still facing the issue,then the best way to deal with it is to hide it by css.

```
 styles={{
          options: {
            zIndex: 1000,
            primaryColor: '#3698DC'
          },
          {
          buttonClose: {
            display: 'none'
          }
        }}
```